# What are the books usually called for studying the computation of GDP?

Tags: reference-request, gdp, national-accounts

What are the books usually called for studying the computation of GDP?

It seems that the economics growth by Barro doesn't discuss about that.

Comment: Could you add you aim ? Do you want to know the three common methods to compute the GDP or you want to do some time series econometric ?

Comment: the three common methods @YM'fr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ultimate reference is the [UN's SNA 2008 manual](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/nationalaccount/sna2008.asp). SNA stands for System of National Accounts. The SNA 2008 is the international statistical standard for the national accounts

Answer (score 1):

Blanchard, Macroeconomics 6th, p. 20 is a good and easy start. If you want more, then yes good directly to the office' publications. The BEA has a very complete documentation.